# Filtering through highcharts series data array

Tags: arrays, highcharts

I have an array from a ajax call that looks like this

```
[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 8, 8]
```

These are actually moment times converted into hour of the day moment(milliseconds).hour(). I'm trying to display these on a column where the x  0 through 24. Like so:

```
xAxis: {
        categories: generateX(24),
            crosshair: true
        },
```

and the function that generates the axis

```
function generateX(num){
    var xAxis = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <= num; i++){
        xAxis.push(i);
    }
    return xAxis;
}
```

Obviously these are categorical data and I want to group these (ie: display count of each number). Does high chart have a simple way of automatically grouping these and then displaying the frequencies from an array type like mine?

I could do a bunch of loop statements and push the counts to 24 different properties but I'd rather avoid doing that.

Comment: No, you need to tell highcharts what the data is. It has no "binning" capability itself. And what exactly are you trying to plot? how many times data = 7 occurs? Over what category? Do you have a sample chart?

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out, I'll add an answer in a min

Answer (score 0):

As @wergeld pointed out, there's no binding capability so I used underscore to get what I wanted

```
    var tempList = null;
    var finalList = [];

    // use underscore to get count of each number and store in tempList

    tempList = _.countBy(array, function(hour, index){
        return currentDiscInHourFormat;
    });

    //loop through the key/val obj that gets produced from tempList and set a multidimensional array in finalList

    for(var key in tempList){
        finalList.push([key, tempList[key]]);
    }
```